# Substituted fonts and Word Automation

Tags: fonts, office-interop, postscript

I have a word document that uses a nonstandard font. It's not embedded but is installed on the machine in question.  In Word 2010, when I print that to a post script file while specifying a certain printer driver (HP Color LaserJet 2800 Series PS), that font gets embedded (subset) just fine.  That's if I do it from the Word application itself.

If I try to do it programmatically using msword::_Document::Printout and specifying the same printer driver, the font in question gets subsituted with something else. I know the same printer driver is being used in both cases. The .ps files generated for both methods list the printer drivers name at the top. Is there some reason going through automation this way would substitute the font but going through the app itself does not?

```
CComVariant vIgnore; 
vIgnore.vt = VT_ERROR;
vIgnore.scode = DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND;

CComVariant vFalse = false;
CComVariant vTrue = true;
CComVariant vOutputFile(m_csTempOutputFile);
CComVariant vOneCopy((int)1);  

 ...
 ....

 m_piApp->SetActivePrinter( (LPCTSTR) csPrinterName); 

 m_Doc.PrintOut(
        &vFalse,//Background, return control while printing? FALSE
        &vFalse,//Append, append output to existing file? FALSE, overwrite file
        &vIgnore,//Range, the page range
        &vOutputFile,//OutputFileName, name of printtofile file
        &vIgnore,//From, starting page (ignored)
        &vIgnore,//To, ending page (ignored)
        &vIgnore,//Item, what content to print, DEFAULT
        &vOneCopy,//Copies, number of
        &vIgnore,//Pages, page range
        &vIgnore,//PageType, even only, odd only, etc
        &vTrue,//PrintToFile, TRUE
        &vIgnore,//Collate,
        &vIgnore,//ActivePrinterMacGX, (mac feature only)
        &vIgnore,//ManualDuplexPrint,
        &vIgnore,//PrintZoomColumn, (printing several pages on one page)
        &vIgnore,//PrintZoomRow,
        &vIgnore,//PrintZoomPaperWidth,
        &vIgnore);//PrintZoomPaperHeight,
```

Comment: and funny enough, if instead of printout, I use the Saveas API to save as PDF - again the font is substituted. If I do the same thing through Word itself, it gets embedded fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some of my systems where I see this, a reboot of the server fixed my issue. It seems sometimes after installing a true type font, you need to reboot the server.

And indeed, on some of my systems, after rebooting, I did see the font get embedded. Why doing the same thing through the Word app didn't need a reboot but going through automation did - I have no idea.

http://www.idautomation.com/kb/ttf-printing.html

Comment: If this is the issue, you can probably avoid a complete server reboot by restarting just the spooler service: `net stop spooler` and then `net start spooler`.

Comment: This matches my experience as well -- sometimes a reboot is needed.  Stopping and starting the spooler service made no difference in my case.

Answer (score 1):

The printer driver you use has various settings which influence the font handling. They control...

- ...whether the font is embedded or not (*'Download fonts to printer'* or *'Use printer fonts'*) and
- ...**IF** it is embedded, then how this is done (*'As TrueType'*, *'Convert to Outlines'*, *'Use substitution table'*, etc.)

**Caveats:** I cannot look it up right now on a real Windows system, I'm quoting these points from memory.

Now these printer driver settings could be set by an administrator, which would make them the defaults for all users.

Each user in turn could have changed these settings to a different mode as well.

Now here comes my *theory*:

- when you do your test from the Word application, you do it for sure while logged in as a certain user, and this user's settings are applied to the PostScript that is generated.
- when you do your test programmatically, you could be in a situation where this process is running as *another*, different user, who has different settings enabled.

It's certainly worth following this track, even if it's only to rule this possibility out...

Comment: Very good suggestion. I actually have played with the "download as soft fonts" options on the driver itself and havent had luck. I did recently have a bit of luck with my issue though. See my answer. thanks